# How to get minimum and second minimum rows for each group

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have a table like

```
fruit      ex.Date      price
banana     01/08/2016   57
banana     05/08/2016   60
banana     12/07/2016   90
grape      03/08/2016   40
grape      06/08/2016   20
grape      08/07/2016   10
apple      25/07/2016   80
apple      18/06/2016   20
```

now i need two tables from mytable
1st table like (based on min date in each fruit group)

```
fruit   ex.Date   price
banana     12/07/2016   90
grape      08/07/2016   10
apple      18/06/2016   80
```

then 2nd table (based on next date in each group)

```
fruit   ex.Date   price
banana     01/08/2016   57
grape      03/08/2016   40
apple      25/07/2016   80
```

Comment: what's the datatype of `ex.Date` ?

Comment: datatype of ex.Date is Datetime

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In order to get the minimum rows for each group:**

```
SELECT 
myTable.*
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    fruit,
    MIN(`ex.Date`) min_date
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY fruit
) AS t
ON myTable.fruit = t.fruit AND myTable.`ex.Date` = t.`ex.Date`
```

**In order to get the second minimum rows for each group:**

```
SELECT 
myTable.*
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    S.fruit,
    MIN(S.`ex.Date`) min_date
    FROM myTable S
    WHERE `ex.Date` > (SELECT MIN(T.`ex.Date`) FROM myTable T WHERE S.fruit = T.fruit)
    GROUP BY S.fruit
) AS t
ON myTable.fruit = t.fruit AND myTable.`ex.Date` = t.`ex.Date`;
```

---

**EDIT:**

To generalize the solution for getting **nth minimum** rows:

> ```
> SELECT 
> *
> FROM 
> (
>   SELECT 
>   *,
>   IF(fruit = @sameFruit, @fruitRank := @fruitRank + 1,
>       IF(@sameFruit := fruit, @fruitRank := 1,@fruitRank := 1)
>   ) AS fruitRankNumber
>   FROM myTable
>   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameFruit := '', @fruitRank := 1 ) var
>   ORDER BY fruit, `ex.Date`
> ) AS rankedFruitTable
> WHERE rankedFruitTable.fruitRankNumber = X
> ```

**Note:** Replace `X` by your expected value. If you want to get rows having the minimum `ex.Date` then replace `X` by `1`. To get second minimum rows for each fruit replace `X` by `2` and so on.

Comment: And the third output?

Comment: Any indication for that in the post? I didn't find any :(

Comment: Just extending the idea

Comment: I guess I'm suggesting that this solution isn't particularly scalable.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks. Needed to add the solution for getting the nth minimum row for each group. Hopefully I will add it tomorrow